# crontab formats

Tags: 12.04, cron

I want to run few crontabs at startup and also at regular intervals. I have used the below format -

```
# M H Dom Mon Dow
  0 7-21/2 * * *   //this will run daily from morning 7:00 to 21:00 clock with interval of 2hours each. ie. 7, 9, 11, 13 and so on.

  @reboot          //this will run everytime the system reboots

  */20 7-21 * * * //this will run for every 10 minutes from 7:00 to 21:00 clock

  0 7-21/4 * * *   //this will run for every 4hours from 7:00 to 21:00 clock
```

These are the 2 different cronjobs Ive set. I doubt if this works well.
Please suggest changes required, if any. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these crontab examples.This gives a detailed explanation of different formats.If you gogle you can find more

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Comment: my main concern was `0 7-21/2 * * * ` is this a valid cronjob setting.